# Получить информацию о ворклогах для issues проекта в джире

Tags: python, python-3.x, jira

Всем привет!

Мне нужна ваша помощь в таком вопросе: у меня есть список issues (среди них эпики, таски, стори, сабтаски и т.д.). Определенным образом я отфильтровал их id и поместил в список:

```
listOfKeys = [id1,id2,id3,id4,id5...]
```

Затем мне нужно получить такую таблицу (данные в которой будут построены на issues, которые есть в списке ключей listOfKeys), как на скриншоте:

[image: смотреть скрин]

Для этого я написал этот «код»:

```
listOfWorklogs=pd.DataFrame()                #table from the screenshot (I used pandas (pd) lib)
lst={}
for i in range(len(listOfKeys)):
    worklogs=jira.worklogs(listOfKeys[i])
    if(len(worklogs)) == 0:
        i+=1
    else:
        for j in range(len(worklogs)):
            lst = {
                    'self': worklogs[j].self,  
                    'author': worklogs[j].author,
                    'started': worklogs[j].started,
                    'created': worklogs[j].created,
                    'updated': worklogs[j].updated,
                    'timespent': worklogs[j].timeSpentSeconds
                }
            listOfWorklogs = listOfWorklogs.append(lst, ignore_index=True)
########### Below there is the recording to the .xlsx file ################
```

Но работает сея конструкция оочень долго. А у меня около 10000 issues.
Знаю, что нужно как-то запускать несколько асинхронных потоков, но понятия не имею, как это сделать(((
Может кто помочь/подсказать/натолкнуть на правильную мысль?
Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 0):

А ты уверен, что библиотека JIRA для Python поддерживает асинхронную работу?

В целом можно попробовать разбить задачу на несколько потоков, но только очень внимательно не передавай в потоки JIRA обьекты (они внутри хранят соединение).

```
from threading import Thread

class WorklogRetriver(Thread):
    def run(self):
        newConnection = JIRA(...)
        running = True
        while running:
            issueKey = self._queue.pop()
            if issue:
                worklogs = newConnection.Issue(issueKey).Worklog()
                # TODO - ...
            else:
                running = False
```

А в главном потоке собственно получи issueKey и распаралеливай уже по потокам.

В целом на сколько я помню, можно как-то заставить JIRA посчитать суммарно сколько времени на задачу в секунду затрачено. Это ковырять API нужно.

P.S. Если есть права на SQL в которм живет JIRA базы может быстрее разово просто один сложный SELECT сделать? Схема вроде бы в свободном доступе лежала на оф. сатйе.

Comment: Да, уверен.
Да, рест апи джиры может показать при определенном запросе тотал времени на задачу, но мне нужна детальная информация. К сожалению, прав на выгрузку из базы нет( Спасибо за подсказку с модулем Thread. Я с потоками ранее вообще не работал, буду ковыряться. Если что-то дельное получится - отпишу.